How to stop VS Code cursor from blinking?
How do I stop the VS Code cursor from blinking? What's the right option in settings.json?

@Gio I don't know, but my guess would be that a) I created the question and immediately answered it myself, some people don't like that and b) it's not really a programming question and quite trivial.

well, it is even encouraged (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=Yes!,to%20answer%20their%20own%20questions.) I think you did a great job

Add the following line to your settings.json (to open it, press CMD/Ctrl + Shift + P and type "Settings"):
  "editor.cursorBlinking": "solid",

The default editor settings and their options are documented at VS Code Default Settings.
An alternative is to use the graphical settings editor.

Open Settings GUI: Press Ctrl + ,
Type "cursor blinking" in the search bar
Change the relevant entry to "solid" from "blinking"

